# having a problem logging in

Tags: bug, login, auto-login

I'm running into an issue currently that is preventing me from logging into StackOverflow on Firefox (and only Firefox, Chrome and IE work fine). I was able to log in to Meta (clearly) as well as other sites like travel, so I'm not sure what's affecting StackOverflow.

Here's a screencast I recorded: http://screencast.com/t/mmUn0tWoecYG

Comment: can log in with firefox on another computer, so perhaps some sort of cookie issue?